# Detecting if POST sent

Tags: jquery, ajax, validation

Is there any solution to detecting if a POST have been sent with jQuery?

My situation is that I have a WP-plugin (Contact form 7) which is sending the data through a jQuery ajax-function. When the form is filled right (validates) the user should be sent to page X.

I have tried with the following without any good results:

```
if ($(".wpcf7-mail-sent-ok").is(":visible")){
        window.location.href = "http://stackoverflow.com";
    });
```

I think this doesn't work because the class "wpcf7-mail-sent-ok" is showing up only when the form is sent and valid by jQuery. So it isn't there to be "detected" for my above code.

How do I solve this issue?

Comment: can you provide a part of your ajax script

Comment: what is in the form action???

Comment: Not sure which code you needed so I posted the hole plugin: http://pastebin.com/wMk8xHdw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can detect DOM insertions with `DOMNodeInserted` event. If you think `wpcf7-mail-sent-ok` is being inserted only after the ajax call then you can bind on this event.

```
$(document).on('DOMNodeInserted', '.wpcf7-mail-sent-ok', function() {
    window.location.href = 'http://stackoverflow.com'
})
```

Comment: live is depricated "As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use .delegate() in preference to .live()."

Answer (score 1):

```
if($(".wpcf7-mail-sent-ok").length)
```

Comment: Didn't work I'm afraid. I think it is because another jQuery function produces the "wpcf7-mail-sent-ok" without re-loading the page. So the code you wrote cant find it because its not in the source code.

Comment: It should detect anything in the DOM, no matter how it got there.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to inspect the traffic or Chrome -> right click -> "inspect element" -> "Network".

Answer (score 0):

Find that ajax on your page and look for its `success` function, put an alert('hello') in there and you'll know if it gets executed.